# Unable to access/find TeamCity localhost page

Tags: tomcat, windows-server-2008, localhost, teamcity

I have a reoccurring problem with TeamCity. On my company I have installed TeamCity three different times and successfully connected them to some kind of SVN-repo.

But after a while I have always got the same error, unable to access localhost, i.e. TeamCity's login-page (I start the browser and it can't find localhost).

I have tried to find a solution but with no success, I also tried to get TeamCity to stop working (to find out what causing the problem) but also without success.

The tricky part is that I don't know why it happens and I have no clue how to fix it. It just happens suddenly. The logs does not tell me anything and all the services/ports/etc is working properly. It just, out of the blue, loses its startpage-connection.

I run TeamCity on a Win 2008 Server R2. So, does anyone have a clue or some ideas that might help me to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's solved. No valid information was to be found in *any* logs. The silly answer was that, for some reason, port 80, that Tomcat uses, was blocked by a "System:4"-process. After some research it turned out to be the AD.

Never would have suspected that since it happened all of a sudden. That is, it worked for a couple of weeks then just one day - nothing.

You'll have to edit

- `TeamCity\conf\server.xml`
- `TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties`

to use another port instead of the default port.

Comment: It happened to me on a reboot, when suddenly IIS was present, running and occupying port 80. I'm certain I didn't install IIS so I can only assume it installed with an update of some kind, which only completed on reboot.

Comment: Just to add: You need to update `Connector` port in server.xml

Comment: FWIW, I had to change the ports and then go end and manually stop/start the "Team City Server" in Services

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity is a java web app running on Tomcat.  There are 10 different error logs findable in

c:\TeamCity\logs

I would look there first.  Also check the windows event log.  You didn't mention which logs you checked, but the windows event log is the less likely place to find the answer because most java applications avoid operating system specific services to maintain portability.